# How can I run a script recursively in a directory

Tags: shell-script, find

I am using the following code to decode JPEG-compressed DICOMs.

```
find ./* -maxdepth 0 -name '*.dcm' -printf 'dcmdjpeg %p %p \n' | sh
```

I run this code inside any folder containing those files.

The problem is that I have a parent folder and a list of sub folders inside this parent folder. Every sub folder contain at least 2000 DICOM (File).
How can I apply this code one time inside the parent folder to be executed in all the sub folders at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `find` command has a switch for that. It's called `-exec`.

```
$ find . -name '*.dcm' -exec dcmdjpeg {} {} \;
```

This will substitute filenames as they're found by `find` into the places where there are `{}`. So in the above we'll be doing this for each filename.

```
dcmdjpeg file1.dcm file1.dcm
dcmdjpeg file2.dcm file2.dcm
...
```

If there are spaces in your filenames you can use this method:

```
$ find . -name '*.dcm' -exec dcmdjpeg "{}" "{}" \;
```

#### Seeing what's happening

You can swap out the command `dcmdjpeg` with the command `echo` and run the above to see the filenames that'll get executed.

*Example*

Say I had this sample data.

```
$ tree
.
|-- 1
|   |-- 1.dcm
|   |-- 1\ space.dcm
|   |-- 2.dcm
|   `-- 3.dcm
|-- 1.dcm
|-- 2
|   |-- 1.dcm
|   |-- 1\ space.dcm
|   |-- 2.dcm
|   `-- 3.dcm
|-- 2.dcm
|-- 3
|   |-- 1.dcm
|   |-- 1\ space.dcm
|   |-- 2.dcm
|   `-- 3.dcm
`-- 3.dcm
```

And now when we run the 2nd example that handles spaces in filenames:

```
$ find . -name '*.dcm' -exec echo "{}" "{}" \;
./2.dcm ./2.dcm
./1/2.dcm ./1/2.dcm
./1/3.dcm ./1/3.dcm
./1/1 space.dcm ./1/1 space.dcm
./1/1.dcm ./1/1.dcm
./3.dcm ./3.dcm
./1.dcm ./1.dcm
./2/2.dcm ./2/2.dcm
./2/3.dcm ./2/3.dcm
./2/1 space.dcm ./2/1 space.dcm
./2/1.dcm ./2/1.dcm
./3/2.dcm ./3/2.dcm
./3/3.dcm ./3/3.dcm
./3/1 space.dcm ./3/1 space.dcm
./3/1.dcm ./3/1.dcm
```

In the above you can see filenames being echoed out twice per file found.

Comment: thanks slm, I am using tsch. Could you please tell me the final code that I suppose to use in my script

Comment: @malshikho - that command I showed you is it.

Comment: You mean the code in first line: $ find . -name '*.dcm' -exec dcmdjpeg {} {} \; and the last two lines are an explanation for the process. Also when I apply this code in the parent folder is it going to work inside all the sub folders in that parent folder?

Comment: @malshikho - I added a bit more details, hope it helps.

Comment: @slm, could you explain why you put two pair of pairing braces?

Comment: Shows the name of the file found twice. Look at the output.